# Is it possible to use a variable from a specific function in another function

Tags: c#, function, variables

Basically I want to input limitInput and after tryparsing it, use bool isInt and limitInputInt in another function

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {

        static void Input()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Integer X?");
            var limitString = Console.ReadLine();
            int limitInt;
            bool isInt = int.TryParse(limitString, out limitInt);
            Console.WriteLine(isInt);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Input();


            if (isInt = true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(limitInt);
            }
            else if(isInt = false) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("this is not an integer");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to input a number as variable limitString, tryparse it and then use limitInt and isInt in a different function.

whenever I run this I get CS0103 The name 'isInt' does not exist in the current context
I do understand this error message but I don't know how to fix it

This code is simplified from my original code but essentially does the same thing (my original code is beyond unreadable)

I'm sure there is a super simple fix but a newbies gotta learn somehow, and I couldn't find any solutions that I could understand

for anyone interested, I'm making a number guessing game in c#
I've previously made one in python but want to learn c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return that variables as method result. In case you need 2 variables, you can use Tuples:

```
 private static (bool, int) Input()
 {
     //...
     bool isInt = int.TryParse(limitString, out limitInt);
     // ...
     return (isInt, limitInt);
 }
```

Then, in your calling method (`Main` in your example) assign result also as tuple:

```
 static void Main()
 {
    var (isInt, limitInt) = Input();
    if (isInt)
        // ...
    else
        // ...
 }
```

More info about tuples you can find in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).